# Breaker for dining room lights

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, code-compliance

If I'm putting in a dedicated circuit for dining room lights, does the current code require it to be arc-fault protected (California)? Or is that requirement just for the outlets?

Comment: As a common room, yes I think so. Lighting-only is not the issue. At the least, just because you only use it for lighting doesn’t mean the next owner won’t tap into it for outlets.

Comment: GFCI is a shock safety thing that's often not applied to lighting as shocks from lighting take creativity or situations were it is required such as over tubs. AFCI is fire safety for the wiring in the walls and applies to pretty much everything. Especially if your walls are subject to, say, seismic events...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unless your area hasn't implemented the latest NEC code, just about everything now requires arc fault protection.

Comment: Yes, specifically CA 2022 California Building Standards Code adopts the 2020 NEC, 210.12(A) "...outlets and devices..."